# Chainlink Node Crashes on Job run containing ethabiencode

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, polygon, chainlink

My chainlink node crashes everytime I run a function with ethabiencode in it

My Node Job is currently set up on polygon mumbai testnet and i can run other request such as direct requests and bridges

```
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "Veri-Test-2"
contractAddress = "ORACLE_ADDRESS"
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
observationSource = """
decode_log   [type="ethabidecodelog" abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)" data="$(jobRun.logData)" topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

decode_cbor  [type="cborparse" data="$(decode_log.data)"]

encode_tx   [type="ethabiencode" abi="fulfillTestingFunction(bytes32 requestID, bytes32 resulttt)" data="{ \\"requestID\\": $(jobSpec.externalJobID),\\"resulttt\\": 48692043686164000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}"]

submit_tx    [type="ethtx" to="ORACLE_ADDRESS" data="$(encode_tx)"]

   decode_log   ->  decode_cbor  ->  encode_tx   -> submit_tx
"""
```

then my eth return function is defined as follows

```
function fulfillTestingFunction(bytes32 requestID, bytes32 resulttt)
    public
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(requestID)
  {
  
    _result = bytes32ToString(resulttt);
  }
```

here is an output of my node after i try run the Job, then i need to restart it

[image]

1. I have created the Oracle and Activated the node on the oracle contract
2. I have funded the Oracle ontract with Polygon
3. I have funded the Contract with the contract with Link to pay for the request
4. I have been able to run other request successfuly but just not submit back to blockchain

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Thanks for this. This might be better as an issue on the chainlink github repo: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/issues

Comment: I have done so as well thanks